# Fetching data from API in React Native with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to fetch data from API in react native using redux but it is not fetching. The API is based on colors which have to fetch, all it is showing just the change button on the screen and not changing backgroundColor after clicking on it

Here is the code :

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from "./reducers";
import BoxCon from './container/box-container';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (

      <Provider store={store}>
        <BoxCon />
        </Provider>



    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

container/box-container.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreators from "../action/index.js"
import Box from '../component/box.js';
//import { actionCreators } from 'redux';

class BoxCon extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Box handleClick={this.props.loadColor} color={this.props.color} />

        )
    }
}

const mapStatetoProps=(state)=>{
    return state
};

export default connect (mapStatetoProps, actionCreators)(BoxCon);
```

component/box.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
export default class Box extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View  style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'${this.props.color}'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onClick={()=>{this.props.handleClick()}} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>
                        Change Color
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE ={
    color:"red"
}

const mainReducer=(state=INITIAL_STATE,action)=>{
    if(action.type==="CHANGE_COLOR"){
        return{
            ...state,
            color:action.color
        }
    } else{
        return{
            state
        }
    }
}

export default mainReducer;
```

action/index.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export function loadColor(){
    return(dispatch) => {
        return axios.get("http://www.colr.org/json/color/random").then((response)=>{
           dispatch(changeColor("#"+response.data.new_color));
        }) .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }); 
    }
}

export function changeColor(color){
    return{
        type:"CHANGE_COLOR",
        color:color
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using single quote at `<View style={{backgroundColor:'${this.props.color}'}}>`
try using backtick

Comment: You don't need to use single quote or back tick
`<View style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color }}>`

Comment: Yeah backtick are useless :D, It's just to point the difference

Comment: Does you api call is fired on button click?  if yes, then remove your single quote one `<View style={{backgroundColor:'${this.props.color}'}}>`, you sould be good to go. if no, revisit the your `mapStateToProps` and apply remove single quote.

Comment: Thanks @Morlo Mbakop , @Onlinogame and @fctmolina. I followed all of your advices and change `onClick` to `onPress` in `onClick={()=>{this.props.handleClick()}}`. And Now, colors are fetching now.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you did not specify a payload.

Change:

```
if(action.type==="CHANGE_COLOR"){
    return{
        ...state,
        color:action.color
    }
}

...

export function changeColor(color){
    return{
        type:"CHANGE_COLOR",
        color:color
    }
}
```

to

```
if(action.type==="CHANGE_COLOR"){
    return{
        ...state,
        color:action.payload
    }
}

...

export function changeColor(color){
    return{
        type:"CHANGE_COLOR",
        payload:color
    }
}
```

and I think it will work.

Comment: Why does he/she need to specify a payload?